# bootstrap bootbox show variable in message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I would like to have the message in the dialog show something like "Choose how you want to kick/ban (playername)"

my current code looks like this

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-ban", function(e) {
    var username = ($(this).attr('id'));
    bootbox.dialog({
       message: "Choose how you want to ban "+$username,
       title: "Ban Player",
       backdrop:false,
       buttons: {
```

didn't feel like the rest of the code mattered

i've tried taken the id from the ancor tag, which is defined by php to be the player name.

but ever since i added the "+$uername" to the message, the dialog wont show.

any ideas?

Comment: just use username because its variable need full code in jsfiddle

Comment: or if you want to user the php variable then put in php tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `username` not `$username` like,

```
message: "Choose how you want to ban "+username,
```

**Full Code**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-ban", function(e) {
    var username = this.id; // you can use it simply without using attr()
    bootbox.dialog({
       message: "Choose how you want to ban "+username,
       title: "Ban Player",
       backdrop:false,
       buttons: {
```

Comment: except for once crucial thing,    this.id doesn't return anything

Comment: It will `return id` if your `element` has `id attribute`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate `php` varialbe Then use in this way,

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-ban", function(e) {
var username = this.id; // you can use it simply without using attr()
bootbox.dialog({
   message: "Choose how you want to ban "+ <?php echo $username; ?>,
   title: "Ban Player",
   backdrop:false,
   buttons: {
```